# How to make Input Type Gallery Images field in html css for Laravel Dashboard

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I want to make a input type gallery Field in Laravel Dashboard to Input gallery Images for Products, I'm not able to do it How Can I do it.

```
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input"id="firstvariantimage" name="product_image">
  <label class="custom-file-label form-control" for="firstvariantimage">
Product Images</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Find some sort of JS library that handles this for you

Comment: can I do it custom

Comment: Considering that all javascript is written custom, you absolutely can. However there's no reason to reinvent the wheel